# Angular: How to get an element by id with an expression from a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Bulky question ahead so let's break this down. I try to achieve a similar behavior like the native `<label>` for `<input>`. I **can't** nest them so I use a style like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" />
Some other content...
<label for="test">Lorem ipsum</label>
```

In my case `<label>` is a custom directive and `<input>` is an arbitrary elment. It could look like this:

```
<p id="test">Some element...</p>
Some other content...
<custom-directive for="test">My directive</custom-directive>
```

Sadly my `id` isn't really static. It is an expression. It could look like this:

```
<p id="test-{{ foo }}">Some element...</p>
Some other content...
<custom-directive for="test-{{ foo }}">My directive</custom-directive>
```

Now to my problem: Inside `<custom-directive>` I want to get the element configured in the `for` attribute. Lets say `foo` has the value `"bar"`set in the `$rootScope` inside `<custom-directive>` I get `foo-bar`. However no matter where I try it (inside `compile`, `link`, `controller`, with or without a `priority`, etc.) the specific element (here `<p>`) has still `test-{{ foo }}`at that time, so I get `null` with `getElementById`.

**How can I get the element outside the diretive, if it has an `id` containing an expression?**

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cd6uooze/

(Note: In my real world app this problem is slightly different. I can actually `getElementById` the right element from a directive even if it the `id` contains an expression. However this works only until the specific template is inside the `$templateCache`. I couldn't really break this down in the JSFiddle, but it the example from the JSFiddle is very similar.)

Comment: Would you be able to tell us what you want to end result of the directive to be? Once IDs and DOM manipulation start getting used in angularjs, I always assume there's probably a better way to achieve the same result.

Comment: As I said I want to archieve something similar like a native label and inputs, but I don't want to focus something, I want to hide or show other elements on specific events on my directive (like click). Normally I would achieve this with a child directive which registers itself on a parent directive, but this only works if I can nest them. (Like the tabs and panes example on Angulars docs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your getElementById code inside `$timeout`

Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76cd1ohx/2/).

Comment: So there is no event or callback I can use which indicates when the ID is correctly resolved? :/ `$timeout` always looks like a hack.

Comment: No there isn't any event or callback for that and in  your scenario you have to execute your dom manipulation code after the binding is done. So we need to use $timeout.

Comment: Okay, I'll mark your answer as correct. Sadly there is no better way.