# populate value of id attribute from controller in template angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controlleras, controlleras

I am writing a `directive` with `angularJs`, with a simple below `html template` and a `contorller as c` 
 
**template:**

```
<p>Input id : {{c.inputId()}}</p> <!--this is for test,correct value is shown-->
<input id="{{c.inputId()}}" type="text" />
```

but the problem is that even the `<p>` tag for test shows correct the value, the `input id` does not get the value. 
I've tried these `id="c.inputId()"`, `id='c.inputId()'`, `id="{{c.inputId()}}"`, `id='{{c.inputId()}}'`, but none of them work. 
Any ideas what is wrong with my code and how can I solve this???

**EDIT 1** 
I think I is better to explain that `documnet.getElementbyId` returns null..maybe It was my mistake that I didn't mentioned it in order to make the question simple and I did not realize that `documnet.getElementbyId` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-attr` to use interpolation in attributes, so in your case `ng-attr-id="{{c.inputId()}}"`

Comment: thank you..but it does not solve the problem..and by the way I've tried populating other attributes without using `ng-attr-X`

Comment: Could you put your code in a fiddle/plunker for us to look at ?

Comment: Martijn's answer should solve the problem. Did you check you `dev console`? The `id` attribute should be replaced by whatever value is returned by your method. Check this plunker which is close enough to what you need. http://plnkr.co/edit/lxHB7Nl6egebFtiKkbBe

Comment: @ThomasSebastian, (@the post owner as well) Thanks to both of you..I've just explained how I solved my problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

to @Martijn answer,  actually it will work with `id` and there is no need to use `ng-attr-id` :) 
 the problem is reading the id when the angular binding has not completed yet, so `document.getElementbyId('#someId')` returns null. 
I've solved it with using `$timeout` in `link` function of my `directive`

thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984403/angular-how-to-get-an-element-by-id-with-an-expression-from-a-directive)..I am not sure if it is the best solution and also I am not happy with my solution.